# iphone app http post error

Tags: php, iphone, ios

I have a php webservice/api(confirmorder.php) to which i am posting a string in a post variable called "userfile". In "userfile" variable i have data like this

```
"<Order><OrderDetail><customer_note>Test</customer_note></OrderDetail></Order>"
```

Now when i pass this data using my browser the script works correctly regardless of the method i use i.e get/post and i get a response in xml which i am supposed to get back.

But when my iphone app is posting data to the php script i am getting this error in response

```
2012-03-01 18:16:52.115 TEX2[11944:207] 
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>403 Forbidden</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Forbidden</H1>
You do not have permission to access this document.
<P>
<HR>
<ADDRESS>
Web Server at xxxxxx.xxx.net
</ADDRESS>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Why is it working ok when i use firefox to post data?? and getting error when i post using my iphone code. Please Reply. Another thing i want to mention is that the PHP version is the latest one 5.3.10 (upgraded recently) and earlier it was working fine when an older version of PHP was installed on the server.

**Edit**

Thanks for replying rckoenes. As i have to share more information and the reply feature cant accomodate my lengthy comment, i am editing my question. yes i printed out the variable userfile. using `echo $_REQUEST['userfile']`. printing fine when passed using browser but not using iphone code. Couple of days ago this client had installed the suhosin extension and due to that only 512 chars were being considered by php and if it is greater than 512 the post was simply ignored by php..then this client removed suhosin and took to another server having PHP 5.3.10. I did the usual debugging and printed out whatever this script is getting from iphone side. But it simply spits out the error msg but works correctly when posted using firefox. Is it due to some php restriction. 5.3.10 has some remote code execution vulnerability patch installed so canit be like my post variable has some tags in it so thats why its ignoring the data but howcome its working ok in browser.

Comment: You are not giving use enough information. Have you cheked the headers? have you printed out the post request? There are to many variables to make any assumption about what is going on.